# Is there any callback option available for Async & Await

Tags: c#, asynchronous

when we use Async & Await in our program then is there any option which tell me that routine is completed.

```
async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await SomeLengthyOperationAsync();
}
```

when SomeLengthyOperationAsync() will be finished then how user will get notification. so guide me how to implement callback option with  Async & Await. thanks

Comment: "which tell me that routine is completed" - yeah, it returns!

Comment: Looking at your questions, do you google anything for yourself or just post a question straight on SO?

Answer (score 1):

This is literally the point of th of async and await keywords! You can simply put code after the the await line. This code will be executed once the lengthy task had completed.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to pattern callbacks using `await`; the remainder of the method is your "callback".

```
async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await SomeLengthyOperationAsync();
  // Notify user the operation is complete.
}
```

If you have more complicated scenarios, you can use `Task.WhenAll` and/or `Task.WhenAny`.

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.